# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : select?fq=id:*dev*&fq=org_id:21&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json&callback=jQuery2030069…_148048

Tags: jquery, solr

```js
 $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/hruser/select?fq=id:*dev*&fq=org_id:18&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json',

                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data)
                            
                        }
                    });
```

Response : 200ok
but error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `json.wrf` parameter to your query string, giving it the name of your callback function.

So your new ajax call will look like this.

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/hruser/select?fq=id:*dev*&fq=org_id:18&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json&json.wrf=callbackfunction',
                        jsonpCallback:'callbackfunction',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data)

                        }
                    });
```

Then you can define your callback function like

```
function callbackfunction(data) {
        console.log(data );
    }
```

Note :  callback can be anything ,it’s just the name of the callback to call, so json.wrf=blah will work too. jQuery will autogenerate a name for you, so you don’t need to worry about it.